# iOS - self.refreshControl not recognized

Tags: ios, ios6

I have this line

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

but it is not recognized and I get a compile error:

```
property refreshControl not found
```

I am working from this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

And they provide this code as though it is supposed to just work. And idea why the compile error happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`refreshControl` is a property of `UITableViewController`.  Check the base class type of your view controller in the .h file.

Comment: thank you! What should I do if I used the storyboard and just dragged the UITableView onto the screen? My class is a regular ViewController.

Comment: You probably just need to change the superclass of your view controller to UITableViewController

Comment: @DanyJoumaa oh yeah wow, I did that change in the .h file and it suddenly compiled - nice :)

Comment: I'm not familer with the sample.  But likely you needed to drag out a UITableViewController, not a UIViewController followed by a UITableView.

Comment: Just rank it and I think I messed something up when I made the .h file @interface SubscriptionController : UITableViewController - any thoughts on how to cleanly fix it?